# Get completion date on tasks without custom coding

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, ms-project

I am building project sites for projects that have already been partially completed. We want to use the project site to track tasks which have been already completed, and those dates.

There is no 'completion date' per se in the Sharepoint project site and it is critical that we be able to record and display completion dates that do not correspond to the date when the actual task is marked complete (by checking the box) in Sharepoint.

Is this possible without custom coding?

Comment: And you want the project completion date to reflect when all of the tasks are complete? Or some other date?

Comment: Question is clear as mud. Is someone supposed to mark the completion date? What is the completion date referring to? Each project? Do you have a column for that?

Comment: Yes, you need to tell us what the rules for 'completion date' are. Is it the date they marked it complete, then what 'date' should it be compared with?

Comment: I don't see why this couldn't be a workflow - triggered by checking the box, SP goes and updates the (custom) Actual End Date field with today's date. You just have to backfill all the already completed tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the wording of your question, it sounds like all you're wanting to do is add additional date fields to the list and manually update those fields and have them display in your list views?

If you're wanting to monitor the record and have it automatically update the date fields, this can be done using SharePoint workflows.  Below is a screenshot of how this might look/work.

Not sure this really addresses your need as you stated that the task items are input after they have already been completed, in which case manually updating them is really the only way I can see that you could do this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want it to do. It feels a lot like Salesforce :) I am TOTALLY new to SP.  I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 4):

**1. Recording completion date of task when it is marked as completed. ( In your case a check box so below formula may change or you)**

You can create a calculated column *Completion Date*

```
=IF([Status]=="Completed",[Modified],"Not Completed")
```

This will capture the date when task is marked completed in the task list.

**2. To track tasks which are already completed and there dates.**

--> Point 1 will help to get completion date , when task is marked completed in the system.

--> Not sure which date you are talking about by this sentense "record and display completion dates that do not correspond to the date when the actual task is marked complete (by checking the box) in Sharepoint." But it is not possible to generate completion date which is not recorded or which is not corresponds to any date we captured in the list by any means.

**3. If you want user to input completion date**

--> You can create a new column as Completion date.

--> else You can have calculated column for it based on task creation date , start date , due date, etc

4. **If you want to have completion date based on other action.( Activity which is not related to Project Task list)**

--> In this case I agree with Rajesh , its not possible without coding. When that activity is completed , need to build structure that captures that activity complete date to its corresponding field in Project Task List.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

Would simple adding a column with 'End date' to the task list suffice? You can fill out your own completion date.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible without coding. You need to do coding for when user complete the task, you store completion date.